# AVAssetExportSession fails on iPhone 3G - but not on iPhone 4

Tags: iphone, ios, audio

Im converting a `*.caf` file using `AVAssetExportSession` it works pretty well on the 4.0 Simulator and on my iPhone 4 testdevice.

Sadly it always fails on an iPhone 3G with following function:

```
AVAssetExportSession *exportSession = [AVAssetExportSession exportSessionWithAsset:avAsset presetName:AVAssetExportPresetAppleM4A];

 if (exportSession == nil) {

      NSLog(@"no export session");

      return NO;

 }

 exportSession.outputURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:self.tempDir];

 exportSession.outputFileType = AVFileTypeAppleM4A;


 [exportSession exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^{



    if (AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted == exportSession.status) {

        NSLog(@"AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted");


 } else if (AVAssetExportSessionStatusFailed == exportSession.status) {

        // a failure may happen because of an event out of your control

        // for example, an interruption like a phone call comming in

        // make sure and handle this case appropriately

        NSLog(@"AVAssetExportSessionStatusFailed");

     NSLog(@"%@", [exportSession.error description]);

    } else {

        NSLog(@"Export Session Status: %d", exportSession.status);

    }

}];
```

The following error is thrown every time.

`Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11823 "Cannot Save" UserInfo=0x16fb20 {NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Try saving again., NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot Save}`

What could be the reason for this?

Answer (score 48):

[11823 error comes when file already exist](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVFoundation_ErrorConstants/Reference/reference.html) on the path where you are trying to save the file

So you should remove the file.

```
- (void) removeFile:(NSURL *)fileURL
{
    NSString *filePath = [fileURL path];
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:filePath]) {
        NSError *error;
        if ([fileManager removeItemAtPath:filePath error:&error] == NO) {
            NSLog(@"removeItemAtPath %@ error:%@", filePath, error);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you save my time .Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the 3G device lacks the hardware codecs to do the relevant transform. Can you play the caf file on the 3G to test it can decode it, and have you tried converting something simple like a wav to prove it can do encode?

Comment: I can play the caf file on the device. Using `exportPresetsCompatibleWithAsset` I found out that only `AVAssetExportPresetAppleM4A` codec is available on iPhone 3G - So my settings should be fine..

Comment: Can you write a file to `self.tempDir`, and is there enough space there for the expected size of the file?

Comment: Yes, I record the file to self.tempDir using AVAudioRecorder prior to converting it.

Comment: But is there enough space for 2x the file you've just written?